# Having the hash and the password, can I recreate the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography, base64

Assuming that I have a couple of strings (hashes?), all of them are 128bit base64 encoded like the following:

```
7UQzDonnNRkwfjWnUf/MBw==
```

The decoded string is in raw binary format, but I know what the plain text value is.
Will I be able to possibly identify the algorithm and encrypt a string on my own, using the same algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not likely. Just like there are a lot of algorithms that can take 1 and 1 and return 2 (you can add them, or you can multiply them and add 1 or you can divide them and multiply by 2 or etc), there are a lot of algorithms that can take your password and return the given ciphertext.

To make things even more difficult, there are often hidden parameters in encryption system such as encryption keys and password salts that you wouldn't have access to.

It might be a fun learning experience to try to find *an* algorithm that provides the expected output for the given input, but with only one data point, this exercise has lots of trivial solutions, for example:

```
encrypt(string input)
{
    //ignore input
    return "7UQzDonnNRkwfjWnUf/MBw==";
}
```